# Trouble understanding `tabs`.

Tags: c

I am reading "The C Programming Language."  I am having trouble understanding Exercise 1-20 on page 34:

> Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop. Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every n columns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

The second sentence is what I do not understand.

Comment: It means that if each tab is four spaces, and you're six spaces in, it would go to column 8, not 10.

Comment: Grijesh: that is NOT what it means. Chris' response is correct.

Comment: @chris post as answer, you're right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's draw it out visually, with tabs being four spaces and each | representing the next tab stop:

```
|---|---|---|---|
```

All the sentence means is that if you're at any of the hyphens (-) and tab from there, it goes to a tab stop (|) instead of four spaces ahead all the time.

```
|---|---|---|---|
      ^press tab here

|---|---|---|---|
        ^end up here
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I think I have a ways to go before that happens.

Comment: Your graphics should start with a tab stop `|---|---`: If you press tab at the start of a line, you move n spaces to the right, not n-1 as in your graphic.