# C++ Escape Character and Reference Variables Output Confusion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So these are the type of examples that make me frustrated because they seem simple, but do not produce the desired result. Consider the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 7;
    int &b = a;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << " ,\tb = " << b << std::endl;

    b = 10;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << " ,\tb = " << b << std::endl;

}
```

Output:

```
a = 7 , b = 7
a = 10 ,    b = 10
```

Can someone please explain to me why the first escape character seems to be ignored and there is no tab, but in the second example the tab is present. Been looking at this example for a while and am no closer to a solution.

Note: I am running this in Visual Studios 2010

Comment: Tabs don't insert absolute spacing. If you'd like a visual, it seems I've done one before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285325/trouble-understanding-tabs/18285381#18285381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`a = 7 ,`" has 7 characters. If there is a tab stop at position 8 (e.g. as set by the [tabs command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tabs) for terminals), appending a tab character effectivly adds the same amount of whitespace as appending a space character.

Comment: Wow I feel stupid, this makes sense though haha. Thanks for the help, will accept the answer when the time limit is up.